# Was there ever a sequel to Alan Dean Foster's "The I Inside"?

Tags: the-i-inside

I read *[The I Inside](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35155.The_I_Inside)* (1984) as a teenager and loved it. I've looked around but never seen anything about a sequel, although the author left the ending where there could easily be one.

Has anyone ever read anything about a sequel, or what he intended to do with the story? I've tried googling but can't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found no indications of a sequel. [Wikipedia has it as a standalone novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster#Standalone_novels) as does [Alan Dean Foster's website](http://www.alandeanfoster.com/version2.0/novels.htm).

As for what Alan Dean Foster planned to do with the story, the only statement I've found from him so far is that, as of [October 11, 2002](https://web.archive.org/web/20021021055841/http://alandeanfoster.com/version2.0/faqframe.htm), he mentions in the FAQ on his website that it's among the stories that Hollywood studios have optioned. His statement might actually be older, as the page is undated. but that's as far back as I could get the Wayback machine to go on that page.